# Travel to Georgia with EU ID Card?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, georgia-country, eu-id-card, portuguese-citizens

OK I need to ask this about Georgia.... I am a Portuguese citizen and want to go there with national ID card. What will the immigration ask me? Do they give some kind of paper to EU citizens while entering?? Sorry for asking something completely off topic but I want to travel to Georgia in the first half of may

Comment: I believe @Crazydre knows this :)

Comment: Why would this be offtopic?

Comment: You can also enter and exit with your Indian passport and e Visa.  Show the Portuguese ID card when you arrive in the EU.

Comment: How will they let me leave for Portugal without a schengen visa on my Indian passport if I get it stamped while leaving Georgia?

Answer (score 4):

I've never been asked anything by them, and I'm Swedish (i.e. also EU).

If using an ID card, you'll get a [migration card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pnsq.jpg) with an entry stamp **if and only if** entering by land from Turkey (at least at the main crossing in Sarpi). If entering by air or sea, you will **not** get one.

However, the ID will be scanned and it will be put on record when you entered and (if entering by air) where you flew from.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57541/discussion-on-answer-by-crazydre-travel-to-georgia-with-eu-id-card).

Comment: OK the Indian embassy is apparently ignorant of the fact that you can travel with two travel documents per travel. So I'm going ahead with it. Will leave India with Indian passport and visa and then enter Georgia with Portuguese citizen card. Then use the citizen card to get back to Portugal. But what do I fill up in the form given to me in-flight?

Comment: @user59683 What form? You don't get any flying to Georgia and Portugal

Comment: There is an immigration form that you get in-flight before landing in India.... guess they don't do it out there.

Comment: @user59683 Nope!

Comment: You mentioned once that while I enter Tbilisi with my ID. I can ask the immigration officer to stamp entry on my Indian passport.... what do I tell the IO?

Comment: @user59683 No, forget about that (like I said, that Agent seems not to know what he's talking about). Just present your ID, nothing else. If they ask whether you have a passport (some officers aren't really used to EU IDs), just say you don't in order to make things smoother

Comment: And if they ask me how I came from India should I show them my Indian passport and tell them I'm a dual national??

Comment: @user59683 Tell them you're a dual national **if asked**, and **only** if they specifically ask for the Indian passport, show it (but **not** the e-visa) However, again, my experience is that they don't ask EU citizens anything, not even where you're flying from (in fact, a lot of them don't speak English). Also, if, for example, flying Tbilisi-Kiev-Zurich and asked in Zurich where I flew from, I just say Kiev (i.e. the last departure Airport). There are no direct flights from India to Georgia, so you'll be connecting somewhere (such as Istanbul or Dubai)

Comment: OK my uncle had a word with the Indian embassy and they said that if I need any assistance from a Indian embassy abroad I need to have an entry stamp. It can be of Tbilisi if I'm using services in Portugal because of the EU travel agreement. So how do I go about doing this??

Comment: @user59683 "It can be of Tbilisi if I'm using services in Portugal because of the EU travel agreement" Becuse they're ignorant and think that Georgia is in Schengen and thus you get no exit stamp when flying Georgia-Portugal. This is wrong - Georgia isn't in the EU or Schengen (not even in Europe) and the freedom of movement does not apply there. So I can only assume they'll change their mind once they notice their assumption was incorrect (which they will notice upon seeing both a Georgian entry and exit stamp)

Comment: @user59683 What I would do, honestly, is get a written confirmation from the Indian embassy that an entry stamp is required. Enter and exit Georgia on the ID card, and then, when entering Portugal, show the ID card, Indian passport and letter from the embassy, and ask that they stamp the Indian passport

Comment: I'm leaving from India in a few days so I don't think I have enough time to get them in writing coz my uncle goes to work and I can't keep bothering him. Will the stamp my Indian passport if I ask them to at the airport? I mean the Indian passport....

Comment: @user59683 They probably will, if you also present your Portuguese ID card and explain why you need the stamp. Explain clearly that the embassy Indian **requires** it for renouncing Indian nationality, and you don't know why, but that's what you were told. As for Georgia, I just called the Indian embassy in Portugal and they said stamps from non-Schengen countries (Georgia too in other words) are irrelevant, so just show your Portuguese ID there

Comment: If you can call them you could have asked them if I can surrender my passport without any entry stamps at all. My uncle asked them but I'm not sure if he conveyed it properly. Please could you do this? If I call from India I'll get charged like 1 euro per minute

Comment: @user59683 OK, so I told them clearly: you are a dual Portuguese-Indian citizen and are going to renounce your Indian citizenship. You have an Indian passport and a Portuguese ID card, the latter of which lets you enter Portugal with no stamps. I said you had been told that, in order to renounce Indian citizenship, you must have an entry stamp in your Indian passport. The officer I spoke to said that the only important Thing is you having entered Portugal legally, for example with a Portuguese ID card.

Comment: @user59683 So, in summary: exit India on your Indian passport and Georgian e-visa, enter and exit Georgia on your Portuguese ID (because Portuguese have much better conditions in Georgia than Indians), and enter Portugal on your Portuguese ID. Some Georgian border officials aren't used to EU ID cards, but the worst that can happen is they'll double check with a colleague or their supervisor that it is indeed accepted for Georgia

Comment: I don't mind if they double check it as long as they grant me entry. I'll only be there for 12 hours. Any good excuse I could give them for such a short trip? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user59683 Just say you have a long connection, and you'll be fine - and again they don't normally ask EU citizens questions about their trip in the first place. For your reference, the centre is about half an hour away from the airport by bus 37

Comment: @user59683 Please let us know how everything goes

Comment: As an Indian citizen I need a travel insurance while entering Georgia. Do I need a travel insurance when I arrive as an EU citizen?....

Comment: @user59683 I'll say it one more time: I'm an EU citizen and they **never** say **a single word** to me. No purpose/duration of trip, no return ticket, no hotel booking, no insurance...nothing. They scan my ID and **that's it**

Comment: I've finally entered Georgia. The immigration lady made me wait for 45 minutes to enter. All the while asking me why I don't have Passport. Finally when she asked the police officer at the last counter he saw the card and said sorry to me and told me to enter. Then said welcome and let me in. She even saw my Indian passport. I told her I'm a dual national. But still she wasn't convinced that Indians can be Portuguese. I even told her that Portugal ruled Goa for 600 years. But after all this. I got to enter

Comment: @user59683 Was this at Tbilisi airport? And did they stamp your Indian passport?

Comment: Yes at Tbilisi airport. No she didn't stamp my Indian passport. She only scanned my ID

Comment: @user59683 I've never entered at Tbilisi airport, and I've never had any issues at Kutaisi airport, but at land borders I have, but only for a few minutes. Personally I now always carry the following government website printout when crossing the land border, which makes things much quicker http://oi65.tinypic.com/ji2f5l.jpg The last text in bold says (among others ) that EU citizens can use IDs

Comment: Now you tell me :p anyway it's alright

Comment: @user59683 Yeah, it's done, and all is well. Hopefully the Indian embassy in Portugal won't make a fuss. Do let us know how that went too

Comment: You said you spoke to someone at the Indian embassy over the phone right.

Comment: @user59683 Yes, it was a man, and he said there'd be no problems as long as you're legally in Portugal

Comment: Hey. Final update. I'm in the UK now and the Indian high commission has accepted my surrender application of the Indian passport. No questions asked. They just asked me how I entered the UK and I said I used the Portuguese passport and they were like, OK. *Phew*

Comment: @user59683 Ah, so you got yourself a Portuguese passport? Nice!

Comment: Yes I did. And thanks a lot for the advise. If I had listened to my agent I would have been in India right now cancelling my voters I'd and subsequent documents